# SendMessage vs SendNotifyMessage in user32.dll api

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, screen-scraping, user32

I've inherited some rather narly "screen scraping" code at work.  It all seems to work fine EXCEPT on some Windows XP machines where click events never make it to the button we wish to programatically "click".

The following snippet is used in various parts of our code to "click" a button.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern static int SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
    static public void SendClick(SystemWindow w, bool WAIT = true, int delay=100)
    {
        if (w != null)
            if (WAIT == true)
                SendMessage(w.HWnd, 0x00F5, 0, 0);
            else
            {
                SendNotifyMessage(w.HWnd, 0x00F5, 0, 0);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            }
    }
```

What confuses me is the difference between SendMessage and SendNotifyMessage.  Any idea why you would want one over the other?

Comment: SendMessage blocks until the message is processed; SendNotifyMessage returns immediately (unless the window belongs to the same thread).

Comment: Also have a look at [`SendMessageTimeout()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx).

Comment: @Benju: did you validate that `SystemWindow w` is the correct window for the button, and that `w.HWnd` is valid? What is the return value of `Send(Notify)Message()` when the button does not response? Does the failure occur only when `WAIT` is either true or false, or does it happen for both? Have you tried using Spy++ or similar tool to monitor window messages and make sure your message (which is [`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx) - do not hard-code its numeric value) is reaching the button?

Answer (score 2):

`0x00F5` is [`BM_CLICK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775985.aspx).  Its documentation contains the following note:

> If the button is in a dialog box and the dialog box is not active, **the BM_CLICK message might fail**. To ensure success in this situation, call the [SetActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311.aspx) function to activate the dialog box before sending the BM_CLICK message to the button.